# Uniform convergence in real valued injective functions sequence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

If $f_{n}$ is a sequence of real valued injective functions that converges uniformily to $f$, then is it necessary that $f$ be injective? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy counter-example :

Pick $f_n(x):= \frac{x}{n+1}$ for $x\in[0,1],n\in\mathbb{N}$

$\frac{1}{n+1}\ge\lvert{f_n-0}\rvert$ which means that $\frac{1}{n+1}\ge {sup_{x\in[0,1]}\lvert{f_n-0}\rvert}$, which means that $f_n$ converges uniformly towards the trivial function, yet $f_n$ is clearly injective while the zero function clearly isn't

Comment: What if $f_{n}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? This example can't be used, there is another that fits this? Thank you!

Comment: Let $f_n(x):=  \frac{Arctan(x)}{n+1}$ for all n and all real numbers x, you'll that this too converges uniformly towards zero while being (bij)injective